# Can a port labelled 1394 be used with a mini-DisplayPort to VGA adapter?

Tags: firewire, dell-latitude, mini-displayport

I have a [Dell Latitude E5520 laptop](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/latit/en/latitude-e5520-spec-sheet.pdf) and I can see there is a port labelled 1394. Does anyone know if you can run a mini-DisplayPort to VGA adapter from it? I am trying to set up 2 external monitors to be used at the same time as the laptop screen itself.

Answer (score 5):

The port labeled 1394 is a FireWire port. Therefore I don't think that you can directly connect a miniDisplayPort adapter on this port. If you have some adapter to connect your VGA to FireWire it could work...

Comment: I really do not want to buy 10 different types of adapters to find 1 that will work :) really annoying :) Been looking around firewire to vga adapters :) thx